# Unix: Overloading Aliases

Tags: unix, bash, alias

What happens if I have this in my bashrc:

```
alias ls="ls -l"
alias ls="ls -a"
```

when I type `ls` they will both match.  Is the last one kept or both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second `alias` command will [redefine](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/alias.html) the alias for "ls". You can double check by running the `alias` command with no arguments, to see which aliases are defined.

Comment: +1 Right answer. No overloading with the alias command.

Comment: Or better yet, `alias ls` will show you what (if anything) `ls` specifically is aliased too.